# Undestanding react router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In this code

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>Topic</h3>
  </div>
)

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>

    <Route path={`/aaa`} component={Topic}/>

  </div>
)

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
         <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
       <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
export default BasicExample
```

component `Topic` which I registered under link "/aaa", never gets rendered.
I tried two approaches but none renders it:

1. If I type url http://localhost:3000/aaa directly (I could understand why in this case it doesn't render the right component). See point 2 below, which I thought had to render right component.
2. Even if I visit **first** http://localhost:3000/topics, which contains the Route for "/aaa", so to my understanding now the "/aaa" route has to be registered. So **after** I visit, /topics, **then** I type
   http://localhost:3000/aaa
   but still it doesn't render `Topic` component.

Can anyone explain why?